# JRI return code 10

Tags: java, r, exception, rjava, jri

I'm new to R and was attempting to call a simple rJava test program from java. I have done the necessary path settings and when 
I am attempting to create a Rengine instance the code is failing. The issue seems to be with **C  [R.dll+0x26036]**. However, I am new to this and not being able to figure out the issue. Any help will be welcome.

My code :

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
public class First_R {
public static void main (String args []) {

    System.out.println("Start");
    Rengine.DEBUG = 5;

    System.out.println("Starting Rengine..");
    System.out.println("R_HOME =" + System.getenv("R_HOME"));
    final Rengine re = new Rengine ();
    // Check if the session is working.
    if (!re.waitForR()) {
        return;
    }
    re.assign("x", new double[] {1.5, 2.5, 3.5});
    REXP result = re.eval("(sum(x))");
    System.out.println(result.asDouble());
    re.end();
}
```

}

**The output:**

Start
Starting Rengine..
R_HOME =D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006c726036,
>   pid=4588, tid=1872

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 **Problematic frame:
 C  [R.dll+0x26036]**

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:

Comment: Have you set the VM options? you need to set up your VM options, for example in netbeans ive inserted the following option for JRI -Djava.library.path='C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\library\rJava\jri\x64'

Comment: You're question ended abruptly: "An error report file with more information is saved as:" ...?

Comment: @YehoshaphatSchellekens, I added `System.setProperty("JRI", "-Djava.library.path='D:/Misc/RLib/rJava/jri/x64'");` to my code. It still returns the same error. Also as I have installed rJava to my exclipse I have set the    path for the dlls and JRI in my preferences.

Answer (score 2):

In Your environment setup, please change R_HOME to `D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0` and not  R_HOME =`D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\`, please let me know if that does the job :), notice that the your code works for me (using nicola's advice as well)

```
package rundavid;

import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;



public class RunDavid {


public static void main (String args []) {



    System.out.println("R_HOME =" + System.getenv("R_HOME"));


    Rengine re = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
    // Check if the session is working.
    if (!re.waitForR()) {
        return;
    }
    re.assign("x", new double[] {1.5, 2.5, 3.5});
    REXP result = re.eval("(sum(x))");
    System.out.println(result.asDouble());
    re.end();
}}
```

the output:

```
run:
R_HOME =C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3
7.5
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Also you need to set up `D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\x64;D:\Misc\RLib\rJava\jri\x64`
This you need to set up in vm options, and not as environment variable.
this is how its done in `Netbeans` (that what im using):

1. Right click on the project, then click on properties
2. Then choose the `run`
3. Insert the VM options as following:
   [image: How to set VM options in Net beans]

Comment: it still does not work for me . Am i doing something wrong with the settings? I am posting the full output here :

Comment: Can you please post all your environment variables?

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME, and PATH properly?

Comment: JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
JRE_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45
PATH : %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;D:\650444\Work\Tools\Octave\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\server;D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\x64;D:\Misc\RLib\rJava\jri\x64

Comment: Look at my new answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize properly your `Rengine`. Try this:

```
Rengine re = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
```

when you create the engine, and everything should work. The constructor without arguments "create(s) a new engine by hooking into an existing, initialized R instance which is calling this constructor" (from the [doc](http://rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html)). This causes the error, since there is not an existing `Rengine` running (I guess).

Comment: I had tried this previously when I was trying to debug my error. Using this line of code does not throw the stack trace error that i have printed in my question , but the program execution terminates with a return code of 2. Using debugging mode in eclipse i can see it is faling in this Rengine instance creation line.